# how to use embed code in javascript variable

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, embed

I have this variable in js :

```
var video_embed = '<script src="https://stream.laminor.academy/1qwyvs9ystd9/embed"><\/script>';

$('.my_video').after("<div class='col-xs-12' id='video_content'>"
 + video_embed + 
"</div>");
```

but my rendered HTML code is :

```
<div class="col-xs-12" id="video_content">
    <script src="https://stream.laminor.academy/1qwyvs9ystd9/embed"></script>
</div>
```

embed code not working!

Thanks for help

Comment: "but my rendered HTML code is" — What do you expect it to be?

Comment: @Quentin, render video tag from my video service

Comment: And why should that happen (bearing in mind that the URL you've used in your example is a 404 error)?

Comment: this url is example. when use `<script src="https://example.com/VIDEO_ID/embed"></script>` in HTML this is work. but I want append with js

Comment: "this url is example" — Obviously, but that doesn't give us anything to go on to debug it. You need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: can you append this script to html tag with js?
`<script src="https://stream.laminor.academy/1qwyvs9ystd9/embed"></script>`

Comment: Well, the code is obfuscated and generates an error in the console.

Answer (score 0):

when you generate script tags after the document is loaded, it won't run.

You need to download the script and execute it :

```js
//Code that will download the script
function loadScript() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
       // Making sure there's no error
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            // Executing the script
            eval(this.responseText)
        } else if (this.readyState == 4) {
            // If the server responded with something else than a 200 OK
            console.warn(this.status)
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "https://stream.laminor.academy/1qwyvs9ystd9/embed", true);
    xhttp.send();
}
// Executing the function
loadScript()
```

Let me know if it isn't working.

Comment: thanks. how to append this function to HTML code?

Comment: @MostafaNorzade I'm not sure for that but maybe if you put the code above in a <script> tag in your div